# Touchpad stops responding/lags up, but I can still move mouse cursor with graphics tablet?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, touchpad, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba C855-2GX. The problem is with the touchpad, it lags for around 15 seconds (up to 2 minutes in worst case). The mouse button doesn't even work.

When the touchpad lags, I can still move the mouse using my tablet graphic. Does this mean my touchpad is the real problem?

I think my problem came from bad RAM... when I installed new software or when I scan PC with antiviruses, or even when I surf in the net with google chrome. I searched about a lot of solutions but they all don't really work:

- Shutdown PC then click shutdown button for 40sec ==> 50% improved lag but it came back after 1 month
- I updated the drivers but know I don't find a new driver for my touchpad.
- Defragmentation of PC - Nothing changed.

Please help, I've only had this laptop for 5 months, and from Day 1 the touchpad has been doing this.

#### System Specs:

- 4GB RAM
- 5400RPM 500gb HDD
- Intel i5 CPU